# Tapdev open function returns me 37 value

Tags: kernel, network-interface, tap

I am trying to create a tun device and tap interface. But the open function returns 37 value. why?

```
fd = open("/tmp/tun", O_RDWR)
```

https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki

NOTE:
It works well in my pc platform and it returns 4(4 is location of tap0 interface)
But I need to run it in ARM cross platform and in this platform the function returns 37.(tap0 location is 3 in this platform).

Comment: Dont you have to insert a kernel model to use that?

Comment: there's no /tmp/tun device, and the /tmp dir is not the right place to mknod device files in. try /dev/net/tun instead. And 37 is a valid fd -- you may have opened 34 + 3 fds before.

Comment: @mosvy there is a tun device in /tmp/tun directory and I can not create a tun device in /dev directory because it is read-only

Comment: @Rui F Ribeiro I dont know but when I run it with sudo command it works correct but I am trying to run without sudo.

Comment: 37 is a **valid** fd; open(2) returns -1 on error

Comment: But I think It should returns 3. (my tap0 interface's location)

Comment: open() will return the next free file descriptor, not any kind of "location" ( there's **no relation whatsoever** between the handle returned by open() and the tap0 interface's index). If you start with the standard fds  0,1,2 and call open() 34 times without any close() in between, the next open will return 37.

Comment: Yes. My opinion is the worst. As you see 37 is the correct value and now my code works well.Thank you all.